# Updating Xpaths in Scrapy Amazon

Tags: python, scrapy

Learning scrapy on Amazon.

[link](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=baby+cribs&ref=nb_sb_noss_1)

I have seen the xpaths for name, reviews, and link (href) changed in the past week.

These are the xpaths

```
REVIEWS = <span class="a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text" style="" xpath="1">
TITLE = <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal" xpath="1"></span>
LINK = <a class="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text a-text-normal" href="
```

When I use the scrapy shell, none of these appears to work.

e.g.

```
response.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text"]/text()').get()

response.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]/text()').extract()
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: modern pages may have complex system to detect bots/script and block them. They may have also complex system to detect device to send different content to desktop, notebook, tablet, phone. Other common problem is that modern pages use `JavaScript` to add elements but `Scrapy` (and `BeautifulSoup`) can't run `JavaScript` and they may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. There is even module `scrapy-selenium`. You could also check in web browser what it displays for Amazon when you turn off JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the request headers:

```
scrapy shell
In [1]: url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=baby+cribs&ref=nb_sb_noss_1'

In [2]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "www.amazon.com",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "TE": "trailers",
   ...: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.372
   ...: 9.169 Safari/537.36"
   ...: }

In [3]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers)

In [4]: fetch(req)
2021-09-25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-09-25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/s?k=baby+cribs&ref=nb_sb_noss_1> (referer: None)

In [5]: response.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text"]/text()').get()
Out[5]: '1,050'

In [6]: response.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]/text()').extract()
Out[6]:
['Did you mean ',
 '3 in 1 Diaper Bag Backpack Travel Bassinet Portable Baby Bed, Baby Diaper Bag with Changing Station, Foldable Baby Crib with Changing Pad (Grey)']
```